# Generate wave image like sound cloud c#

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio, waveform

When I am trying to generate wave form image by passing mp3 stream to the following       function it is throwing overflow exception at g.DrawLine call. Please correct me where I am going wrong.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public static void DrawNormalizedAudio(ref float[] data, Color color)
{
   Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(1800,200);            

   int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
   int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
   int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
   {
      g.Clear(Color.Black);
      Pen pen = new Pen(color);
      int size = data.Length;
      for (int iPixel = 0; iPixel < width; iPixel++)
      {
        // determine start and end points within WAV
           int start = (int)((float)iPixel * ((float)size / (float)width));
           int end = (int)((float)(iPixel + 1) * ((float)size / (float)width));
           float min = float.MaxValue;
           float max = float.MinValue;
           for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
           {
              float val = data[i];
              min = val < min ? val : min;
              max = val > max ? val : max;
           }
           int yMax = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((max + 1) * .5 * height);
           int yMin = BORDER_WIDTH + height - (int)((min + 1) * .5 * height);
           g.DrawLine(pen, iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMax,
           iPixel + BORDER_WIDTH, yMin);
          }
        }

        bmp.Save("D:\\waveimage.png"); 
    }

    public float[] FloatArrayFromStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
    {
        return FloatArrayFromByteArray(stream.GetBuffer());
    }

    public float[] FloatArrayFromByteArray(byte[] input)
    {
        float[] output = new float[input.Length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, i * 4);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that you are drawing an image that has more output columns than input, which would give you values for `min` and `max` (and therefore `yMin` and `yMax`) that are out of range.  I would expect that the `yMin` calculation would throw the exception in that case.

You should be clamping the `yMin` and `yMax` values to the size of the drawing area on the canvas, then adding the `BORDER_WIDTH` offset before (or during) the call to `g.DrawLine`.